# problema con modal solo me abre en el primer registro

Tags: php, mysql, modal

Estoy haciendo un condigo para abrir una ventana modal desde una tabla el problema es que solo me abre la ventana nodal en el primer registro ya que si le doy en el segundo o en cualquier otro que no sea el primero no me abre, me abre bien pero solo en el primer registro en los otros registros no abre ni nada
este es mi código donde envió llamar al modal

`````
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-hover" style="width:100%;">
                      <thead>
                      <tr>
                   
                          <th style="width: 30px;">Nombre</th>
                       
                          <th style="width: 30px;">Telefono</th>
                          <th style="width: 30px;">Total adeudo</th>
                         
                         <?php 
 $sql3 = "SELECT * 
FROM articulos a 
INNER JOIN subastas_s sss ON a.id_subastasS = sss.id_subastasS
WHERE sss.id_subastasS = '1'GROUP BY a.id_subastasS";
$consulta3 = mysqli_query($con, $sql3);
while ($rowedit1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta3)) :
?>
                          <th style="width: 30px;"><?php echo $rowedit1['fecha_de_pago1']; ?></th>
                          <th style="width: 30px;"><?php echo $rowedit1['fecha_de_pago2']; ?></th>
                          <th style="width: 30px;"><?php echo $rowedit1['fecha_de_pago3']; ?></th>
                          <?php endwhile ?>
                          <th style="width: 10px">Total</th>
                          <th style="width: 10px">Detalles</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <?php
                        $sqlCliente1   = ("SELECT COUNT(precio) AS ventas, SUM(precio) AS comprasC, SUM(precio)/sss.pagos as pag,SUM(precio)*sss.comision/100 AS comi,
                        art.ids, art.comprador, art.vendedor, art.nombre, sss.id_subastasS, sss.pagos, art.fecha_de_pago1 as fe, art.id_subastasS, art.precio, sss.comision, art.precio, u.Cedula, u.Username, art.deuda,
                        u.Nombres, u.Apellidos, u.Direccion, u.Telefono 
                        FROM articulos art 
                        INNER JOIN usuario u ON u.Username = art.vendedor 
                        INNER JOIN subastas_s sss ON sss.id_subastasS = art.id_subastasS 
                        WHERE sss.id_subastasS ='1' GROUP by art.vendedor;");
                        $result1 = mysqli_query($con, $sqlCliente1);
                        
                         while ($rowedit = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
                          
                           $Nombre = $rowedit["Nombres"] ;
                           $Apellidos = $rowedit["Apellidos"] ;
                           $vendedor = $rowedit["vendedor"];
                           $Telefono = $rowedit["Telefono"];
                           $totalV =  $rowedit['comprasC'];
                           $fecha_de_pago1 =  $rowedit['pag']-$rowedit['comi'];
                           $fecha_de_pago2 = $rowedit['pag'];
                           $total =$fecha_de_pago1+$fecha_de_pago2+$fecha_de_pago2;
                       ?>
                          <tr>
                   
                        <td style="vertical-align:center;text-align: center;"><a href="verperfil.php?id=<?php echo $vendedor;?>"><?php echo $Nombre ?> <?php echo $Apellidos?></a></td>

                        <td > <?php echo $Telefono; ?></td>
                        <td style="vertical-align:center;text-align: center;">$ <?php echo number_format($totalV, 2, '.', ','); ?></td>

                        <td style="vertical-align:center;text-align: center;" >  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" title="Detalles" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editv<?php echo $rowedit['vendedor']; ?>">
                             
                              $ <?php echo number_format($fecha_de_pago1, 2, '.', ','); ?></button>
                              <?php include('vendedores/ModalEditarv.php'); ?></td>

                        <td style="vertical-align:center;text-align: center;" ><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" title="Detalles" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editv<?php echo $rowedit['vendedor']; ?>">
                             
                              $ <?php echo number_format($fecha_de_pago2, 2, '.', ','); ?></button></td>

                        <td style="vertical-align:center;text-align: center;" ><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" title="Detalles" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editv<?php echo $rowedit['vendedor']; ?>">
                             
                              $ <?php echo number_format($fecha_de_pago2, 2, '.', ','); ?></button></td>
                        <td style="vertical-align:center;text-align: center;" >$ <?php echo number_format($total, 2, '.', ','); ?></td>
                            <td>
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deletev<?php echo $rowedit['vendedor']; ?>">
                              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><!--! Font Awesome Free 6.4.2 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License) Copyright 2023 Fonticons, Inc. --><style>svg{fill:#ffffff}</style><path d="M135.2 17.7L128 32H32C14.3 32 0 46.3 0 64S14.3 96 32 96H416c17.7 0 32-14.3 32-32s-14.3-32-32-32H320l-7.2-14.3C307.4 6.8 296.3 0 284.2 0H163.8c-12.1 0-23.2 6.8-28.6 17.7zM416 128H32L53.2 467c1.6 25.3 22.6 45 47.9 45H346.9c25.3 0 46.3-19.7 47.9-45L416 128z"/></svg>
                              </button>

                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" title="Detalles" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editv<?php echo $rowedit['vendedor']; ?>">
                              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><!--! Font Awesome Free 6.4.2 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License) Copyright 2023 Fonticons, Inc. --><style>svg{fill:#ffffff}</style><path d="M256 80c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32s-32 14.3-32 32V224H48c-17.7 0-32 14.3-32 32s14.3 32 32 32H192V432c0 17.7 14.3 32 32 32s32-14.3 32-32V288H400c17.7 0 32-14.3 32-32s-14.3-32-32-32H256V80z"/></svg>
                              </button>
                            </td>
                          </tr>


                          <!--Ventana Modal para Actualizar--->
                          

                          <!--Ventana Modal para la Alerta de Eliminar--->
                          <?php include('vendedores/ModalEliminarv.php'); ?>


                        <?php } ?>
</tbody>
                    </table>

```` y este es es codigo del modal que mande a llamar
`````

" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editv" aria-hidden="true">
  
    
      
        
            Detalles de abono
        
        
          ×

```
  <form method="POST" action="./vendedores/altaabono.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="vendedor" value="<?php echo $rowedit['vendedor']; ?>">

        <div class="modal-body" id="cont_modal">
       
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="vendedor" class="col-form-label">Nombre del vendedor</label>
              <input type="text" name="vendedor" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $rowedit['Nombres']; ?> <?php echo $rowedit['Apellidos']; ?>" required="true" disabled>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
  <label for="metodo_pago" class="col-form-label text-black" style="text-align: center;">Método de pago utilizado*:</label>
      <input type="text" name="metodo_pago" class="form-control"  list="option3"
        id="metodo_pago" required>
      <datalist id="option3">
      <option value="Efectivo">Efectivo</option>
      <option value="Tarjeta">Tarjeta</option>
      <option value="Cheque">Cheque</option>
      <option value="Transferencia Bancaria">Transferencia Bancaria</option>;
                

      </datalist>
  </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="abono" class="col-form-label">Cantidad de abono*:</label>
              <input type="text" name="abono" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $fecha_de_pago1; ?>"  required="true">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
           
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar Cambios</button>
        </div>
   </form>

   <table class="table table-striped table-hover" style="width:100%;">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
               
                      <th style="width: 30px;">Nombre</th>
                   
                      <th style="width: 30px;">Metodo de pago</th>
                      <th style="width: 30px;">Abono</th>
                      <th style="width: 30px;">Fecha de pago</th>
              
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <?php
                    $sqlCliente12   = ("SELECT * 
                    FROM historial_de_pagos pag 
                    INNER JOIN subastas_s sss ON pag.id_subastasS = sss.id_subastasS
                    INNER JOIN usuario us ON us.Username = pag.nombre
                    WHERE sss.id_subastasS = '1' AND pag.nombre='$rowedit[vendedor]'GROUP by pag.fecha_de_pago;");
                    $result12 = mysqli_query($con, $sqlCliente12);
                    
                     while ($rowedit2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result12)) {
                      
                       $Nombre = $rowedit2["Nombres"] ;
                       $Apellidos = $rowedit2["Apellidos"] ;
                       $metodo = $rowedit2["metodo_pago"];
                       $abono= $rowedit2["abono"];
                       $fecha_de_pago = $rowedit2["fecha_de_pago"];
                      
                   ?>
                      <tr>
               
                    <td style="vertical-align:center;text-align: center;"><?php echo $Nombre ?> <?php echo $Apellidos?></td>

                    <td style="vertical-align:center;text-align: center;"> <?php echo $metodo; ?></td>
                    <td style="vertical-align:center;text-align: center;"> $ <?php echo number_format($abono, 2, '.', ','); ?></td>

                    
                    <td style="vertical-align:center;text-align: center;" ><?php echo $fecha_de_pago; ?> </td>

                   
                    </tr>
                   
                     </tbody>
                     <?php } ?>
                </table>
  

</div>
```

````

solo en el primer registro me funciona en el segundo no abre el modal
[image: imagen de la tabla de registros]
[image: imagen del modal]

Comment: Me pasó lo mismo usando Django. Era porque el modal debía ir en un bucle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que comentas. parece ser algún problema con la identificaciones de los Modales.

En tu código se puede ver que creas un Modal para cada fila de la tabla.

Lo que te sugiero es que una vez que renderiza la pagina. Mires el código fuente de la misma y revisa  a ver si los Modales están correctamente identificados.

Parece una tontería pero por las dudas ,fíjate.

Que este id en el botón

```
        data-target="#editv<?php echo $rowedit['vendedor']; ?>">
```

que puede ser así en el html

```
        data-target="#editv10">
```

tenga su correspondiente

```
    id="editv10"
```

en el Modal.

saludos

Comment: ya lo solucione era por problema de la id por que tiene que ser unico y el campo que tenia no era el id de la llave primaria